# Apple retina support for images in HTML

Tags: html, ios5, safari, mobile-safari

On Apple's website it looks like they have support for retina displays. Does it work the same way that it does on iOS with a @2x image?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of good walkthroughs on how this is done, including: http://mir.aculo.us/2012/06/26/flowchart-how-to-retinafy-your-website/

[image: Retinafy Your Website]

Comment: it is amusing but I strongly suggest http://caniuse.com/#feat=srcset as the current best answer to this question.

Answer (score 13):

- Store your images in /img/logo.png (regular version) and /img/logo@2x.png (retina version)

JS for Head-Tag

```
var retina = 0;
try {
    retina = Number(window.devicePixelRatio);
} catch(e) {}
retina = (retina > 1) ? 1 : 0;

var dt = new Date();
dt.setTime(dt.getTime()+(30*24*60*60*1000));
document.cookie = [
    '_r=' + retina,
    'expires=' + dt.toGMTString(),
    'path=/img/'
].join(';');
```

mod_rewrite for images

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} _r=1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} img/
RewriteRule ^(.*)(.gif|.jpg|.png)$ $1@2x$2 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 5):

Webkit devs have added the srcset attribute to the <img/> tag, which is currently in Webkit Nightly (not in any released Safari version as of Aug 28, 2013). This is a W3C standard, so hopefully other browsers will support it soon too. It has the benefit of graceful degradation since older browsers that don't support the tag will just use the normal image.

Example:

```
<img src="normal-image.jpg" srcset="better-image.jpg 2x">
```

Here is a blog post concerning the feature: https://www.webkit.org/blog/2910/improved-support-for-high-resolution-displays-with-the-srcset-image-attribute/