# Why does iOS scale images up?

Tags: cross-browser, responsive-design, mobile-safari, pixel

Why does iOS scale images up? I am building a site and want it to be mobile friendly, when I look at it on iOS my pixel-based images are getting scaled up for some reason.

Shouldn't the browser keep the images the right size? I have been testing it mostly in chrome using Dev Tools and setting it up to emulate iphone 4 and the images don't scale at all, it displays them as they are supposed to be.

I took a couple screen shots and the iphone width its taking is 640px, but my media query is as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width: 479px)
```

What am I doing wrong? I can't find a solution to this. I need the pixel font images to stay pixely. Same for my splash screen. Screen shots available if you need....

Comment: By scaled up, do you mean doubled?

Comment: Yes I suppose I do now that I've spent a while reading on this. Trying to figure out what to do about this doubling, it makes my pixel images look terrible.

Answer (score 2):

You probably haven't been seeing the issue because your emulator isn't retina display, and therefore your images aren't being scaled, but your device is probably an iPhone 4 or later, and therefore has retina display, which assumes it needs to scale images unless directed otherwise.

Regarding devices with retina display, image resolution works in the browser similarly as it does on the device.  If you want crisp images, you need to specify a separate image for the retina display.  This stack overflow post has a few suggestions for implementing it: [Apple retina support for images in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11476953/apple-retina-support-for-images-in-html)

Comment: The iPhone 4 also has the retina display. The last one without it was the 3GS.

Comment: You are correct.  Updated my answer to reflect this mistake.  Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't seem to get the images to display right as I'm using a sprite. The flow chart from that post is nice, but it doesn't solve my problem (it also assumes you are using OSX, not windows to code).

Comment: @chabuku Can you confirm that what you mean by "using a sprite" is that you are using a CSS sprite sheet.  The flow chart does address that case.  Can you share your revised media query and other relevant CSS?